# Search Places with FusedLocationApi

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, fusedlocationproviderapi

Actually I am using the FusedLocationApi for getting the user current location and after that i will add the marker on the Map and it's working fine..
Now i am adding a EditText on the MapFragment and the purpose of editText is if the user enter another location than my marker move to the New location...

So my Question is:

**Is it Possible to find the places or Address through the FusedLocationApi because someOne Suggest me to use the Google Places Api**

Answer (score 2):

Use google place autocomplete for get location of search address on map. 
[Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete)

Comment: can u give me the any tutorial link

Comment: @DhruvTyagi here the link of sample project-
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to search places in google places api, you can use PlaceAutocompleteFragment and get the location and search it through Latlong.

The problem you will face while just adding a Edittext is when the location is non recognizable by google maps api then it will show no place and keeps you thinking about the exact name instead PlaceAutocompleteFragment will help to guess you the exact places.

Implement -  PlaceSelectionListener
and add following code

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment;
    PlaceSelectionListener ps;
autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.search1);

set listner -   autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);


public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        if (m_map == null) {
            return;
        }
        g = place.getName().toString();

        final LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
        m_map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 21));


    }
```

XML-

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
    android:id="@+id/search1"

    >
```

Comment: oky, so should i remove the FusedLocationApi and implement the 
google places api because it also provide the current location of user

Comment: it's working fine but can i change the fragment to customized SearchView

Comment: Please provide me example (like what)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it Possible to find the places or Address through the FusedLocationApi because someOne Suggest me to use the Google Places Api

You have to use [Google places Api](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/) to convert coordinates into addresses and vice-versa. FusedLocationApi is only helps to find gps coordinates of your phone.

Comment: is there any problem is arise it i used both the api

Comment: You can use both of them if you need. @DhruvTyagi

Comment: if i used both of them, so there is no memory/ performance issue will arise in future

Comment: nop, they are developed and maintained by google. you don't have to worry about them